# SSL Support for sunspot (solr) requests

Tags: solr, sunspot, rsolr

In Rails project we are using sunspot gem for Solr full text search engine.
Sunspot is built on top of the RSolr library, which provides a low-level interface for Solr interaction.

Is there any possibility to set that RSolr requests to SOLR server is **HTTPS** not **HTTP**

Answer (score 1):

This is already supported by RSolr. Just set your url with the https protocol and the port to 443.

You can see how it works here:

```
https://github.com/mwmitchell/rsolr/blob/master/lib/rsolr/connection.rb
```